# Returns an error : index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: unity, c#

[image]

```
public int Money1;
public Text MONEYtext;

public void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("VideoCard", JsonUtility.ToJson(VideoCard));
}

public void Load()
{
    VideoCard = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameObject[]>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("VideoCard"));
}

private void Update()
{
    MONEYtext.text = Money1.ToString();
    Money1 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Money1"); 

    //----------------------------------------

    if (BuyCard <= 4)
    {
        BuyButton.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        BuyButton.SetActive(false);
    }

    

}



//--------------------------------------------------

public GameObject BuyButton;
public int BuyCard = 0;
public GameObject[] VideoCard;




private void Start()
{
    BuyCard = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BuyCard", BuyCard);
    Load();
}

public void BuyCards()
{
    if (Money1 >= 299)
    {
        BuyCard++;
        Money1 -= 299;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money1", Money1);
        PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BuyCard", BuyCard);
        VideoCard[0].SetActive(true);
        Save();
    }
}
```

}

I can't understand why it gives an error , because the size of the array is 5 , I put the value of the first element of the array

Comment: to be fair, the error message is pointing at line 67 and that might not even be in this script. And for future, dont post code in screenshots, use the code markup

Comment: I'm sorry that I sent the photo, the first time on this forum. Yes, the error screen on 67 is not the same, it also gives an error on line 66 , I don't know why, it gives VideoCard[0]. SetActive(true);

Comment: The error you posted is for line 67 for the MoneyText script. Since a functioncall can't give you the indexoutofrange error, this is not the MoneyText script. To help you for this, we would need to see the correct one.

Comment: Edited the question*

Comment: In this case you could show us your VidoCard array from the inspector (screenshot here is ok) and any code that is relevant to VideoCard that gets executed before the BuyCards() call.

Comment: This error is telling you that your `VideoCard` array has nothing in it. You probably forgot to initialize it or assign a value to it in the inspector, or you accidentally overwrote the inspector data with a blank zero-sized array. If you have trouble finding the source of the problem you should edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: every line of code and scene setup step a reader would need in order to reproduce the problem in a new, empty project. Once we have that, we can re-open the question for answers.

Comment: Edited the question*

Comment: did you ever saved something? if not, after load from start there are no elements in the VideoCard and you get the outofbounds error

Comment: yes, my friend, I have already found this error . When starting the game in the inspector, my array simply becomes 0 elements, although I register 5 there. How can I fix this ? Immediately write the size of the array in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deserialize GameObjects from JSON the way you are attempting to do here.

`VideoCard = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameObject[]>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("VideoCard"));`

[It tells you so right in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) - so please don't neglect to read it, especially when troubleshooting a problem!

> Only plain classes and structures are supported; classes derived from UnityEngine.Object (such as MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject) are not.

So what's happening is that when you try to deserialize the GameObject array from JSON, the method refuses to do this forbidden thing, just like the docs tell you it will, and you get back an empty array.

Trying to access the first element of an empty array naturally throws an exception - it doesn't *have* a first element!

If you want to deserialize information stored in UnityEngine.Object types, you'll need to first create the objects you want within your scene or via script, and then load the data *into* them using eg. [FromJsonOverwrite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html) for `MonoBehaviour` components on those objects.

So your real problem here appears to be "How do I save and load information about the player's purchases". Asking about a the exception only obfuscates that problem. So in future, please ask about what you are trying to accomplish, not about [standard exceptions you can easily search on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%20outside%20bounds&searchOn=3).

Comment: In addition to that, even if he loads them correctly, he still might get the same error if there is no data to load (never saved before something) and trying to access the first element

Comment: Thank you very much , I will understand . Can you tell me some video or article about: Downloading and saving purchases?

Comment: I'd recommend using your favourite search engine, or searching past Q&A here  It's a topic we've covered quite a few times already.

Comment: Okey . thanks))

Comment: Damn, I'm trying to rewrite the code for FromJsonOverwrite and it doesn't work(

Comment: Because you are using a screwdriver for a problem that demands a hammer. You do NOT actually want to serialize game objects or components. What you want to serialize is a series of "yes/no" answers — "did the player buy item n?". That's an array of bools, not an array of game objects. Then you can iterate over that array and set the active state of your corresponding game object to true/false based on the boolean value you loaded from your saved preferences.